# Updating specific rows in a table that is a list of lists

Tags: mysql, sql, list

I have a table containing lists. The first column is a unique index of the list, the second contains the order in the list (1,2,3 etc.) and then there are several other columns. One of the other columns contains the list separator (";"), but obviously only in the first N-1 rows of the list. That is, the lists having only one row (item) do not have the separator, the lists with 2 rows have the separator only in row 1, etc. The last row (N) in any list should have no separator in the respective column.

Starting from the initial state where no separator is present in any row, what is the statement to correctly fill in with separators ?

Sample data (only relevant columns):

```
1 1 ; 
1 2 <empty>
2 1 <empty>
3 1 ;
3 2 ;
3 3 <empty>

etc.
```

Comment: Some sample data, and expected result, please!

Comment: are duplicates allowed in the list, or does one specific maximum exist?

Comment: @Nico **Yours is a beautiful self-join**. I did something ~similar 10 minutes ago, but using a temporary table to store the id and count() of each individual id. No, no duplicates allowed in column 1 - i.e. no two different lists have the same value in column1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution should work if there are no duplicates allowed in the lists:

```
  UPDATE listtable t1 
  SET t1.column3 = ';'
  WHERE t1.column2 < ( SELECT MAX(t2.column2) 
                       FROM listtable t2 
                       WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 )
```